# Render Latex code with chart.apis.google.com

Tags: url, math, google-api, web, latex

I've found out that you can use a Google tool to render LaTeX code into nice equations. Example:

[Latex equation (click to see)](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cdisplaystyle%5CLarge%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7De%5E%7B-x%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5C;dx=%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%5Cright)%5Csqrt%7BM%5Ccdot%5Cpi%7D%5Chspace%7B30mm%7Dx%5Cin%5Cmathbb%7BR%7D%5Chspace%7B30mm%7D(1))

Basically, I can use the URL + Latex code and I'll get back a `*.png` with the equation:

URL: `http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=`

Latex code: `\displaystyle\Large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\;dx=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\sqrt{M\cdot\pi}\hspace{30mm}x\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{30mm}(1)`

I can not find any documentation about this service/tool. Is it going to be supported in the future? Can I use it without any concern for a site in order to render LaTeX code into nice equations?

Thank you!

Regards,

LC

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the solution you are looking for, but in markdown you can display a picture as follows:

`![](<url>)`

When I use your URL I get:

[image]